# Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup not working

Tags: powershell, azure

I try too add some Security roules in my Azure NSG via Powershell, but

```
Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup
```

doesn't seem to work, it alway returns nothing. I can't select a NSG by Name too

```
Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name myname
```

Although

```
Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceNameContains nsg
```

finds my NSGs.

What do I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup`** is meant for NSG's created using the classic deployment model (Old Portal). This will yeild output only if you have classic NSG's in your subscription.

You have indicated that you get output when you use the **`Find-AzureRmResource`** commandlet. Now this is a commandlet for the resources created using the ARM deployment model in Azure. One easy way to identify the Resource Manager commandlets is to look for the letters **`RM`** in the commandlet.

Looks like you have NSG's created using Resource Manager, so try the following:

```
Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name  nsg1 -ResourceGroupName "KaushalRG"
```

> Looks for network security group "*nsg1*" in resource group "*KaushalRG*"

More information on the deployment models in Azure can be found here: [Azure Resource Manager vs. classic deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model)

Comment: Thank you so much! It was difficult to get this out of the somtimes confusing documentation by MS